# Can't get the correct value of scrollHeight for a textarea - VueJs, Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Am trying to get the value scrollHeight of a `texteara` filed, the problem is when i use the document object : `document.querySelector("#textarea-element").scrollHeight`, i have a correct value , 
but when i’ve tried to do it with `refs` the value is wrong and didn’t change.
I’ve made a detailed jsfiddle for these behaviors please see below:

```js
 new Vue({ 
  el: '#app' ,
  data: {
    height: 'auto',
    scrollHeightUsingRefsVuejs:'',
    scrollHeightUsingDocumentObject: ''
  },
   methods:{
    resizeTextarea (e) {
      this.scrollHeightUsingRefsVuejs =              this.$refs.messageBox.$el.scrollHeight

      this.scrollHeightUsingDocumentObject =       document.querySelector("#textarea-element").scrollHeight
      
      console.log(this.scrollHeightUsingRefsVuejs, this.scrollHeightUsingDocumentObject)
    }
  }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.11/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.11/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <v-text-field
            color="cyan darken"
            label="Text field"
            multi-line
            rows="2"
            placeholder="Start typing..."
            ref="messageBox"
            @keydown.native="resizeTextarea"
            :style="{height: height}"
            id="textarea-element"
            ></v-text-field>
         <p>
         Scroll Height Using Refs Vuejs : <strong>{{ scrollHeightUsingDocumentObject}}</strong>
         </p>
         <p>
         <span style="color:red">(Wrong)</span> Scroll Height Using Refs Vuejs : <strong>{{ scrollHeightUsingRefsVuejs }}</strong>
         </p>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
```

(To see the value of scrollHeight type anything if the textearea filed)

Comment: You should add the code in your post, instead of referring an external site

Comment: code added here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this.$refs.messageBox.$el.scrollHeight` refers to parent node `input-group` generated by Vuetify that’s way the value seems wrong , all we need just to add a selector to tearea node like this `this.$refs.messageBox.$el.querySelector('textarea').scrollHeight`